# relative paths (cant figure out)

Tags: c#, relative-path

I have a image at location

> C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Folder\bin\Customer\latest\data\help\pic.png";

I want to use this image in file located at

> C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Folder\Tab\User\Configuration\file.cs";

If I use absolute path of pic.png in file.cs I can access the image. But I want to use relative path of the image in the file.cs.

How can I calculate relative path of **pic.png**
to the **file.cs**

ps: i have already looked at the link stackoverflow.com/questions/9065089/calculate-relative-filepath

and it is not working for me. It would be really great if some body could answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
"..\..\..\bin\Customer\latest\data\help\pic.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the part of the path that is the same:

```
bin\Customer\latest\data\help\pic.png
```

If you do the same on the current path, you are left with the three levels `Tab\User\Configuration`, so you need to go down three levels to get to the point where the paths meet:

```
..\..\..\bin\Customer\latest\data\help\pic.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Once the code is compiled (which it must be, in order to execute it), it has no notion of your `.cs` files. All of the code that they contain is compiled into the executable. It is not kept separate, and the executable does not know where the `.cs` files used to be stored on disk at the time of compilation.

Relative paths work relative to your executable's working directory. By default, compiled executables are placed into the `bin` folder and executed by the debugger using this location as the working directory, so that's where your `pic.png` file will need to be, too.

To make this happen automatically, add your `pic.png` file to your project, then set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "true". This will cause the compiler to automatically copy the image file to the same directory as the compiled executable file. Then you can use paths relative to your application's directory as follows:

```
string loadPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(typeof(MyClass).Assembly, "pic.png");
```

Better yet, embed the image directly into your project as a resource, then you don't need to distribute a separate image file or muck about with fragile paths.

Answer (score 0):

Wy do you want a relative path from file.cs. File.cs is just a code file. A file with text, nothing more. The file cannot access the pic. Or do you have code inside of that file and that code is to access the pic?

If you, you are not talking about a relative path from file.cs to you pic. You are talking about a relative path from your EXE-file to your image. In that case you have to know where the compiler will place your image during compile time.

If the image is not part of project and just a file somewhere on your computer. I suggest you make a configuration setting in your app.config with an absolute path to that pic.